# How to know in which files react component is getting exported in whole existing react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, frontend

I am working with one react project and I am new to react. I was used to doing backend stuff. So my question is in a big project you can track to class instances by clicking their references in visual studio. So we don't have to go in each and every file to find where it is being used.
Is there any way like that in React with Visual studio code. to track the component where it's been imported in the whole app. So we don't have to go in each and every file to find whats the used case of that component.
For example, I have this Modal.js stateless component. And I want to know where it's being exported in whole app so I can know whats props are coming to it and how it is used without going each and every file to find its imports.[image]

Comment: this may help .https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en,  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-sight/aalppolilappfakpmdfdkpppdnhpgifn

Answer (score 0):

One way, albeit simple, is to use the search functionality of Visual Studio Code to search "import Modal" (make sure it is case-sensitive).

This should return each instance/file where you import the component in question.

The search function can be found on the left toolbar where the magnifying glass is.